# reading exif information when uploading multiple images

Tags: javascript, image, filereader, exif

On my website, I let users upload multiple images at a time.  I'd like to check the EXIF rotation tag of each uploaded image to manually rotate the image in the browser if necessary.

I found the following response for reading the EXIF rotation value for an image:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7585267/1720985

This works for me when I upload a single image, but it doesn't work when I try to upload multiple images because fr.onloadend finishes after all images have already been read.

My current strategy is to save the corresponding image names and rotation values into a hash (rotate_images) and use this hash later to apply the rotation to the rendered images on the page.

This is currently what I have:

```
  $('#file').change(function(){    
    for(var i = 0; i<this.files.length; i++){
        var file = this.files[i];
        var file_path = this.files.item(i).name;
        if(file_path){
            var startIndex = (file_path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? file_path.lastIndexOf('\\') : file_path.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var filename = file_path.substring(startIndex);
            if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
              filename = filename.substring(1);
            }
            console.log('uploading image ' + filename);
        }
        fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onloadend = function(){
          console.log('getting exif');
          var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
          var orientation = exif.Orientation;
          console.log(filename +' has orientation ' + orientation);
          if(orientation != 1){
            rotate_images[filename] = orientation;
          }
        }
        fr.readAsBinaryString(file); 
    }
  });
```

When I look at the logs, I get the following:

```
uploading image camera.JPG 
uploading image robot.JPG 
uploading image snack.jpg 
getting exif 
snack.jpg has orientation 8 
getting exif 
snack.jpg has orientation 8
getting exif 
snack.jpg has orientation 1
```

You can see from the logs that it's reading the last file.  **How can I delay my for loop until after each file is read?  Or is there another way to read EXIF orientation information from multiple files?**

Here are the scripts I'm using for reading the EXIF information:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/exif.js

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/binaryajax/binaryajax.js

Answer (score 0):

Posted too soon!  I found the answer from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815648/1720985

This was my final code:

```
  $('#file').change(function(){    
    for(var i = 0; i<this.files.length; i++){
      (function(file){
        var file = file;
        var file_path = file.name;
        if(file_path){
            var startIndex = (file_path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? file_path.lastIndexOf('\\') : file_path.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var filename = file_path.substring(startIndex);
            if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
              filename = filename.substring(1);
            }
            console.log('uploading image ' + filename);
        }
        fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onloadend = function(e){
          console.log('getting exif');
          var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(e.target.result));
          var orientation = exif.Orientation;
          console.log(filename +' has orientation ' + orientation);
          if(orientation != 1){
            rotate_images[filename] = orientation;
          }
        }
        fr.readAsBinaryString(file); 
      })(this.files[i]);
    }
  });
```