# How to use JavaScript FileReader in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

```
 let base64Data: string;
 let attachment: Attachment;  
 let blob: Blob;
 docList.forEach(([pdfDoc, title]) => {
            blob = pdfDoc.output('blob'); 
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
              base64data = reader.result;
              attachment = new Attachment();
              attachment.setFilename(title);
              attachment.setContent(base64data);
              attachment.setType('application/pdf');
              attachments.push(attachment);
            }
         });
```

*pdfDoc* is a **jsPDF**; **Attachment** is my own class with fields as indicated.

If I run the above code in debug mode and add breakpoints, the *attachments* array is populated as I expected. Otherwise the array ends up blank. I know there is an issue with synchronizing the looping and the the **FileReader**. I found the following answer

[Looping through files for FileReader, output always contains last value from loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815625/looping-through-files-for-filereader-output-always-contains-last-value-from-loo)

but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with Promises?

Comment: Either way, the problem is not with the return value from FileReader, it's the fact it reads _asynchronously_. You're logging the array before it gets populated.

Comment: I've heard of Promises; not certain how to use them. Edited question--I realize the issue is asynchronicity.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the main problem is, that you kill your array `attachment` with each loop on the one hand and on the other hand you simply missed the plural s.

```
 let base64Data: string;
 let attachment: Attachment;  <<== plural s is missing
 let blob: Blob;

 docList.forEach(([pdfDoc, title]) => {
        blob = pdfDoc.output('blob'); 
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          base64data = reader.result;
          attachment = new Attachment(); <<== kills the array and overwrites it
          attachment.setFilename(title);
          attachment.setContent(base64data);
          attachment.setType('application/pdf');
          attachments.push(attachment); <<== never writes the value anywhere
        }
     });
```

So try it this way:

```
 let attachments: Attachment; // with plural s

 docList.forEach(([pdfDoc, title]) => {
        const blob = pdfDoc.output('blob'); 
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          const base64data = reader.result;
          const attachment = new Attachment(); // without plural s
          attachment.setFilename(title);
          attachment.setContent(base64data);
          attachment.setType('application/pdf');
          attachments.push(attachment); // writes to the intended array

          // how to know when the last item was added?
          if(attachments.length === docList.length) {
              showListContent();
          }
        }
     });

     function showListContent() {
         console.log(attachments);
     }
```

Avoid variables with unnecessarily broad scopes as often as you can. function scoped variables should always be your first choice, if applicable.

Comment: All good advice, but still incomplete. There is no way of knowing when `attachment` will be fully populated with this code.

Comment: Point taken. Solved it.

Comment: @user3803175:  Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem. Thanks in advance. Lynx