# Upload image to array of base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to make a upload image and preview, want to make all selected images to base64 and create an array from it, but after `onload` and `array.push` array return empty, any idea what's wrong? I'm using this code in `reactjs` but for demo to share you I managed to use `jQuery`

```js
function handleImage(e) {
  let image = e.target.files;
  let result = [...image];
  let array = [];

  result && result.map(function(img, i) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(img);
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      array.push(fileReader.result);
    }
  })
  console.log(array) // return empty!
}

$('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
  handleImage(e)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onChange="handleImage" />
```

Comment: It's normal, you are calling an asynchronous function. Look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815625/looping-through-files-for-filereader-output-always-contains-last-value-from-loo